# Which statistical test to use for binned data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, descriptive-statistics

I researched for hours but cannot find the direction for the right test to use. I have a frequency distribution which shows bins on the x-axis that contain amount spent:

0-5\$
6\$-10\$
greater than 10\$

What statistical test shall I use if I wanted to compare the sample population mean of two independent groups that have such data distribution?

Also, would it change the test type if the individual amounts within the bins are continuous, I.e. \$2.11 instead of \$2?

I would truly appreciate any help as I am really stuck on a direction.

Answer (score 1):

First, "sample population mean" is confusing. You compare the samples in order to make inferences about the population.

Second, you cannot compare the means of these two, since you have an unbounded upper group. You would have to make additional assumptions about the distribution,  both within each of the first two (0 to 5 and 6 to 10) - which is relatively easy - and about over 10 - which is going to be hard.

So, you could treat the dollar data as ordinal and do something like a Jonckheere Terpstra test. You might be able to estimate the medians (depending on the distribution).

Answer (score 0):

One potential direction is using [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).
It is a good way of 'modeling' the relations between frequency distributions of more than one variable.